# Distrubute students by percent criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have criteria which value is percent.

```
criteria = {"Top" => 20, "Excellent" =>  30, "Average" => 30, "Poor" => 20
```

I have student hash. Keys are student id and values are student score

```
students = { 1 => 80,
             2 => 90,
             3 => 30,
             4 => 50,
             5 => 120,
             6 => 90,
             7 => 50,
             8 => 50,
             9 => 50,
             10 => 30}
```

Crietria is added by teachers. Student places are calculated this way, because i cant get for example 2.5 students:

```
students_positions = criteria.map {|k, v| (students.count * (v.to_f/100)).ceil }
f=> [2, 3, 3, 2]
```

First thing i do is sorting students by their value(score)

```
sorted_students = students.sort {|a1,a2| a2.last <=> a1.last }.to_h
=> {5=>120, 2=>90, 6=>90, 1=>80, 8=>50, 4=>50, 7=>50, 9=>50, 3=>30, 10=>30}
```

The result should be 20%(2 student positions) of students from student hash get 'Top' criteria, 30%(3 student positions) get 'Excellent' and etc. If two students have same score but are placed in different criteria group should both be in previous critera group. For example One is in Top with score 90 and other is in Execellent with score 90, second one must be moved to Top crietria group.

How can i split students by criteria

Best regards,
Georgi

Comment: `students` does not have `*` method. It is not clear what you are doing with it.

Comment: @sawa sorry i forgot to change it. Its students.count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the given expressions (the first of which is not a Ruby expression) to Ruby expressions:

```
criteria = {"Top" => 20, "Excellent" =>  30, "Average" => 30, "Poor" => 20}
students = {
  1 => 80,
  2 => 90,
  3 => 30,
  4 => 50,
  5 => 120,
  6 => 90,
  7 => 50,
  8 => 50,
  9 => 50,
  10 => 30
}
```

Converting the values to something useful:

```
n = 0
accumulated_counts =
criteria
.each_with_object({}){|(k, v), h| h[k] = n += students.length * v / 100.0}

# =>
# {
#   "Top"       => 2.0,
#   "Excellent" => 5.0,
#   "Average"   => 8.0,
#   "Poor"      => 10.0
# }

students_by_score =
students.group_by(&:last).sort.reverse.map{|a| a.last.map(&:first)}

# => [[5], [2, 6], [1], [4, 7, 8, 9], [3, 10]]
```

Distributing the students:

```
n = 0
accumulated_counts
.each_with_object(Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = []}) do |(k, v), h|
  h[k].push(*students_by_score.shift) while n + h[k].length < v
  n += h[k].length
end

# =>
# {
#   "Top"       => [5, 2, 6],
#   "Excellent" => [1, 4, 7, 8, 9],
#   "Average"   => [],
#   "Poor"      => [3, 10]
# }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yuor answer help me. Just in distrubuting of the students need from poor to move in Avarage. which is for example 3 places so poor should be empty. I will fix that based on your code. Thank you very much again